# Angular 12 - display data in an Array using an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interpolation, two-way-binding

Hello Fellow Community,

I am experiencing a problem currently on my angular 12 project :

I would like to display an array named todos which contains all of my object variables. However even tho I can see on the console that my objects are being added to the array : todos, there seems to be a problem (with my observable maybe) because they are not displayed on the html page.

I have 2 components "add-todo" and "todos" as well as 1 service "todoService".

Here is my code :

````
//todo.service.ts :

 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Todo} from '../models/todo.model';
import {Subject} from "rxjs"

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodoService {

  todos:Todo[]=[];
  todoSubject=new Subject <Todo[]>()

  constructor() {

    setTimeout(()=>{
    this.todos=[
      {
        firstname:"Youssef"
      },
      {
        firstname:"Yacine"
      },
      {
        firstname:"Ismail"
      },
    ];

    this.emitTodo();
  },3000)
   }

   addTodo(todo:Todo):void{
     this.todos.push(todo);
     this.emitTodo();
     console.log("Dans todoservice :"+this.todos);
   }

   emitTodo():void{
     this.todoSubject.next(this.todos);
   }
}

//todos.component.ts :

 import { Component,OnInit,OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import {TodoService} from '../services/todo.service';
import {Todo} from '../models/todo.model';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css']
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  todos;
  todoSub;

  constructor(private todoService:TodoService){}

  ngOnInit():void{
    this.todoSub=this.todoService.todoSubject.subscribe(
      (value:Todo[])=>{
        this.todos=value;
        console.log("Dans todo value :"+value);
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.log("Erreur "+error)
      },
      ()=>{
        console.log("Observable complete");
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnDestroy():void{
    this.todoSub.unsubscribe();
  }



}

//todos.component.html :

   <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let todo of todos;">

  {{todo|json}}


</div>
<p>todo works!</p>

//and finally,

//add-todo.component.ts :

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from '../models/todo.model';
import {TodoService} from '../services/todo.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-todo',
  templateUrl: './app-todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-todo.component.css']
})
export class AppTodoComponent implements OnInit {

  todo=new Todo();

  constructor(private todoService:TodoService, private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit():void{

    this.todoService.addTodo(this.todo);
    console.log("Dans add-todo :"+this.todo);
    this.router.navigate(["todos"]);
  }

}

add-todo.component.html :

<p>{{todo|json}}</p>

<form #addTodoForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <label for="name">Firstname :</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" [(ngModel)]="todo.firstname" required>

  <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="addTodoForm.invalid">Add Todo</button>
</form>```

This is what it shows when I "ng serve" the code :

[![todos.component.html][1]][1]

Then I add a new todo :

[![add-todo.component.html][2]][2]

Then it redirects to the todos.component.html again but it doesn't display all the todos like before :

[![todos.component.html][3]][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P1NQ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/diIDX.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgKxE.png
````

Comment: are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No no errors but the todos array does not show when I do {{todo|json}}

Comment: It seems to working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vhwpph?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @HarunYilmaz It works when everything is in the same file but not in separate components I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to alter arrays and objects in Angular (or any library or framework) immutably for change detection to take place.

Objects and arrays are reference types so they store the location of their memory and doing a push on them does not change the location of memory for them.

Every time you want to change arrays and objects in Angular, do them immutably (assign new values so the location in memory changes and change detection takes place). The `maps` might not be needed but I have added them so the objects inside of the array have new locations in memory as well.

```
addTodo(todo:Todo):void{
  // this.todos.push(todo);
  this.todos = [...this.todos.map(todo => ({ ...todo })), todo];
  this.emitTodo();
  console.log("Dans todoservice :"+this.todos);
}

emitTodo():void{
  this.todoSubject.next([...this.todos.map(todo => ({ ...todo })]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response ! Unfortunately it still doesn't display the todo objects on the todos.component.html page after I add one todo

Answer (score 0):

you are storing `todos:Todo` in the service class. And then try to access `todos` in your component by injecting that service into your components.

```
constructor(private todoService:TodoService){}
```

It's not going to work that way. Please get some idea about how dependency injection works.

Possible workaround,

1. you can store data in local storage or session storage to access them in different components
2. you can use Ngrx like data storing technology (recommended large-scale applications)
3. store data in a local file (Not recommended for large-scale applications)